# Add to Wikipedia's code?

Tags: open-source, wikipedia, codebase

I know that the *wiki concept* is let people from around the world contribute and everything. Now is there a way to add code ("contribute") to Wikipedia's codebase? Open-source?

**For eg.** I'd like to offer a *poll* to every Wikipedian (registered user) on their user-page asking whether they're deletionists (rather have less) or additionists (rather have more)

**I'm sure** many would have great ideas that they could contribute .. like FireFox addons.

Any way to add-on or add to the Wikipedia software? Even if you're constantly under moderation and every change is verified by Wikipedia employees, heck, you get to update *the* Wikipedia!

Comment: Does this question belong here in SO? I am not sure.

Comment: He's wanting to program something and asking if its possible (in this case if its possible to contribute to that project). I think it is very programming related.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd contribute to [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki). However, I strongly suspect you won't get features like polls accepted into the codebase (or at least not adopted by Wikipedia). I suspect that a feature like that would already have been implemented if enough folks on Wikipedia wanted it.

Comment: Pity you can't really add-on to Wikipedia's code though. I knew about these many freely available (open-sourced?) Wiki engines like MediaWiki.

Comment: @Jarvis, You can always branch off them isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can update the code that is actually going on at http://www.wikipedia.org but you could always take an open-source wiki software already out there and customize it to add in the functionality you would like.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're referring to creating a plugin for [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki).